# Upgrade struts web Project to java 1.7

Tags: java, struts2, itext, upgrade, java-7

We are planning upgrading our web project to java 1.7 from 1.6.

We are using Struts 2.0.9 and iText library 2.1.4.

I want to make sure that are this(struts & itext) API compatible with JDk 7.
I tried to find this thing in release notes but didn't found any thing.

Could any one tell me where i can find compatibility matrix for both (struts and itext) with jdk 7. Or any idea about the same.

How should i research for the same.

Comment: Just do it you can find all the answers.

Comment: You can see [Struts Migration Guide](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/migration-guide.html).But about `JDK`, `Struts2` & `itext` are compatible with both JDK 6 and 7. I have tried changing the version in Eclipse. No conflicts for JDKs found.

Comment: While you're at it, you might want to upgrade to a more recent iText version. iText 2.1.4 dates from November 11, 2008. That's more than five and a half years ago. Many bugs have been fixed during those years.

Comment: JDK 7, and Struts 2.0.9 ?!! iText 2.1 ??? Time for some upgrade. I suggest JDK 7, Struts **2.3.16.x**, iText **5.x**. The latest GPL iText version is 2.1.7, not 2.1.4, but [it's deprecated](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14213851/1654265).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Part 1: JDK**

[JDK 1.7 new Features](http://marxsoftware.blogspot.in/2011/03/jdk-7-new-interfaces-classes-enums-and.html)

[JDK 1.7 Backward Compatibility](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/compatibility-417013.html)

[Incompatibilities between JDK 7 and JDK 6](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/compatibility-417013.html#jdk7)

**Part 2: Struts 2**

Apache Struts 2 requires officially minimum Java 5 :

```
Servlet API 2.4
JSP API 2.0
Java 5
```

Reference : [Struts 2.0 Release notes](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.0.x/)

For Struts version migration  [Struts version migration guide](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/migration-guide.html)

**Part 3: itext**

For **itext backward compatibility** no more info available after JDK 5

But still if you want to search

[itext Backward Compatibility](http://support.itextpdf.com/node/94)

[itext versions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14213851/1459174)

[itext Changelog](http://itextpdf.com/changelog)

**Part 4 : Compatibility Matrix**

> ```
>              JDK 5(year 2004)      JDK 6(year 2006)          JDK 7 (year 2011)
> ```
>
> **Struts 2.0 onwards**      Requires at least 5              Compatible               Compatible
>
> **itext 2.1.7 to 5.0.6**  Requires at least 5           Compatible

**After year 2011** Reference : [itext wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IText)

> **itext5.0.6 onwards**                                                Compatible                 Compatible
>
> **Previous versions of iText** (Java up to 4.2.1 and C# up to 4.1.6)

**Part 5 :Making the move**

To do research is fine, to take a decision of upgrade is also good. But it would be better if you focus why upgrade?

1. Reduce risk (New versions have Fixes of bugs)
2. Reap rewards
3. Realize research
4. Enhancement in features

To upgrade does not mean to use visual studio 2010 instead of visual studio 2005.

Take into account the time you’re wasting due to crashes, slow-running software or other difficulties caused by technology that’s less than it should be.

If you feel it is recommended to be up-to-date with market industry standard feel free for upgrade.

it’s a good idea to reevaluate your software and systems every year.

**EDIT:**

[Why shouldn't I use itext 2.x (or iTextSharp 4.x)?](http://www.itextpdf.com/salesfaq)

**iText 5.x uses generics, so we require Java 1.5 at minimum. Versions before 5.x.**

[Functionality comparison iText 2 v iText 5](http://itextpdf.com/functionalitycomparison)

***edits are invited to improve this answer.***

Comment: `JDK 5` launched in **2002** started support for **annotations** and `itext2.0` onwards uses annotations in code as mentioned [here](http://itextpdf.com/changelog/200). Got this page and search for string **"Extra method to add the name (NM) of an annotation"** .. So we can understand that it should be compiled with minimum `JDK 5`.

Comment: Is java 7 is compatible with struts 1??