# Configuring struts2 with jasper reports

Tags: java, struts2, jasper-reports

I am trying to configure Struts 2 with jasper. I have tried this using a little example but I got an error I was unable to recover this after spending two days on it. I have mentioned the error log and other code examples I have used.

```
Unable to load configuration. - [unknown location]
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:70)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init_PreloadConfiguration(Dispatcher.java:429)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:471)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.InitOperations.initDispatcher(InitOperations.java:74)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.init(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:51)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.initFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:273)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:254)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.setFilterDef(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:372)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:98)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4562)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$2.call(StandardContext.java:5240)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$2.call(StandardContext.java:5235)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
    Caused by: Parent package is not defined: jasperreports-default - [unknown location]
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.buildPackageContext(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:660)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.addPackage(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:508)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.loadPackages(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:290)
at org.apache.struts2.config.StrutsXmlConfigurationProvider.loadPackages(StrutsXmlConfigurationProvider.java:112)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.impl.DefaultConfiguration.reloadContainer(DefaultConfiguration.java:239)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:67)
... 16 more
    Jan 28, 2015 7:36:54 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext filterStart
    SEVERE: Exception starting filter struts2
    Unable to load configuration. - [unknown location]
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:483)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.InitOperations.initDispatcher(InitOperations.java:74)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.init(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:51)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.initFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:273)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:254)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.setFilterDef(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:372)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:98)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4562)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$2.call(StandardContext.java:5240)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$2.call(StandardContext.java:5235)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
    Caused by: Unable to load configuration. - [unknown location]
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:70)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init_PreloadConfiguration(Dispatcher.java:429)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:471)
... 14 more
    Caused by: Parent package is not defined: jasperreports-default - [unknown location]
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.buildPackageContext(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:660)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.addPackage(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:508)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.loadPackages(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:290)
at org.apache.struts2.config.StrutsXmlConfigurationProvider.loadPackages(StrutsXmlConfigurationProvider.java:112)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.impl.DefaultConfiguration.reloadContainer(DefaultConfiguration.java:239)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:67)
```

struts.xml

```
    <action name="TestReportExportSupport!*" class="TestReportExportSupport">

        <result name="success" type="jasper">
            <param name="location">our_compiled_template.jasper</param>
            <param name="dataSource">myList</param>
            <param name="format">PDF</param>
        </result>

    </action>
</package>
</struts>
```

Action class
     public class JasperAction extends ActionSupport {

```
/** List to use as our JasperReports dataSource. */
private List<Person> myList;

public String execute() throws Exception {

    // Create some imaginary persons.
    Person p1 = new Person(new Long(1), "Patrick", "Lightbuddie");
    Person p2 = new Person(new Long(2), "Jason", "Carrora");
    Person p3 = new Person(new Long(3), "Alexandru", "Papesco");
    Person p4 = new Person(new Long(4), "Jay", "Boss");

    // Store people in our dataSource list (normally they would come from a database).
    myList = new ArrayList<Person>();
    myList.add(p1);
    myList.add(p2);
    myList.add(p3);
    myList.add(p4);

    // Normally we would provide a pre-compiled .jrxml file
    // or check to make sure we don't compile on every request.
    try {
        JasperCompileManager.compileReportToFile(
                "S2_WEBAPP/jasper/our_jasper_template.jrxml",
                "S2_WEBAPP/jasper/our_compiled_template.jasper");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return ERROR;
    }

    return SUCCESS;
}

public List<Person> getMyList() {
    return myList;
}
```

}

Jars used
1. jasperreports-1.2.5.jar
2. itext-1.3.jar
3. jdt-compiler.jar

Can anybody help me to resolve this. I tried this out 2 days... with lot's of solutions given in the internet.

Comment: [iText-1.3.jar](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14213851/1654265) ?

Comment: Not enough information to help. What libraries are you deploying? Do you have the S2 JR plugin deployed?

Comment: What's wrong with iText-1.3 ....?

Comment: No Dave I haven't use a s2 JR plugin

Comment: What are you waiting for http://struts.apache.org/docs/jasperreports-plugin.html

Comment: Hi I found the issue here. I included the struts2-jasperreports-plugin-2.1.8.1.jar and jdt-compiler-3.1.1.jar.                                                           I also added -XX:PermSize=256m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m to server for raise perm space(But this is not related with the above issue).  Thanks Dave

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi I found the issue here. I included the struts2-jasperreports-plugin-2.1.8.1.jar and jdt-compiler-3.1.1.jar. I missed the struts2-jasperreports-plugin-2.1.8.1.jar. 
I also added -XX:PermSize=256m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m to server for raise perm space(But this is not related with the above issue).

Thanks Dave for your clue.